# BackgroundWorker.IsBusy staying true at all times during serial port operations?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, backgroundworker

I am working on a Data Acquisition and Logging project which has two windows (forms). On the main window, there is a trigger button which opens another form (second form) showing the message "Please wait while the channels' data is being acquired" and acquires data serially by sending a token through the COM port and then saves the acquired data of 13 DAQ cards to a sql database. The second form does all the work in a background thread so that the clock timer on the main form also keeps on ticking (time stamps needed for charting).

[image]

The problem is that on triggering the serial port, the RunWorkerAsync() method of the BackgroundWorker class stays busy i.e BackgroundWorker.IsBusy = true at all times and hence the serial port cannot perform the required write and read operations. My question is can serial operations be performed like this in the background thread? Or do I look for other options?

The relevant code chunk of the Main Form is:

```
//////////////Triggering, DAQ and DB Logging/////////////////////////

    private void Button_Trigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                            
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        
        c_DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        button_Trigger.Enabled = false;

        Form form4 = new WAIT_FORM();
        form4.ShowDialog();

        MessageBox.Show("data acquisition and logging finished");

        

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
   }
```

Form4 code: (There are 13 DAQ Cards polled one by one)

```
 BackgroundWorker serialRtx = new BackgroundWorker();

 serialRtx.DoWork += serialRtx_DoWork;

 SerialPort serialP = new SerialPort("COM1", 57600);  

 private void Timer_Wait_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        if (cardNo == 13)
        {
            cardNo = 1;
            serialP.Close();
            Close();

        }



        if (!serialRtx.IsBusy) // serialRtx.IsBusy = true all times
            serialRtx.RunWorkerAsync();

 private void serialRtx_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] send_Packet = { 170, 170, 170, (byte)cardNo };

        while (cardNo < 13)
         {

        try
        {
            send_Packet[3] = (byte)cardNo;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                serialP.Write(send_Packet, i, 1);
                Console.WriteLine(send_Packet[i]);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }


        }

        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            string str = caught.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }

        cardNo++;

        //if (cardNo == 13)
        //{
        //    cardNo = 1;

        //}            
        
    }

    }
```

**Code Update:**

```
 public WAIT_FORM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serialP.DataBits = 8;
        serialP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        //serialP.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
        serialP.Parity = Parity.None;
        
        serialP.DataReceived += serialP_DataReceived;

        ////serialP.WriteTimeout = 3000; 
        ////serialP.ReadTimeout = 3000;
        
        serialP.Open();            
       
        serialRtx.DoWork += serialRtx_DoWork;            

        if (!serialRtx.IsBusy)
            serialRtx.RunWorkerAsync();

        serialRtx.RunWorkerCompleted += serialRtx_RunWorkerCompleted;
        
    }
private void serialRtx_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {          
            byte[] send_Packet = { 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 2 };
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("Card no=");
                    Console.WriteLine(cardNo);
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        serialP.Write(send_Packet, i, 1);
                        Console.Write("ds=");
                        Console.WriteLine(send_Packet[i]);
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                    }

                }

                catch (Exception caught)
                {
                    string str = caught.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);
                }
        }
        
private void serialP_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (serialP.BytesToRead > 0)
            {                
                dataBit1 = serialP.ReadByte();
                Console.Write("dr1=");
                Console.WriteLine(dataBit1);

                dataBit2 = serialP.ReadByte();
                Console.Write("dr2=");
                Console.WriteLine(dataBit2);                
                               
                try
                {               
                    logData[sample_No, chNo - 1] = ((dataBit1 * 256) + dataBit2); // data[bitCount];//two byes per one DAQ channel
                    logData[sample_No, chNo - 1] = (logData[sample_No, chNo - 1] * 10 / 32768) - 10;//engineered value
                    Console.Write("sample_No=");
                    Console.WriteLine(sample_No);
                    Console.Write("chNo=");
                    Console.WriteLine(chNo);
                    Console.Write("logdata=");
                    Console.WriteLine(logData[sample_No, chNo - 1]);

                    chNo++;

                    if (chNo > 8)
                    {
                        sample_No++;
                        chNo = 1;
                    }

                    if (sample_No > 3999)//total 4000 samples of 8 channels
                    {
                        cardNo++;
                        sample_No = 0;
                    }
                   

                    
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                { }                
            }
        }
private void serialRtx_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
        
        private void WAIT_FORM_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            serialP.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Does DoWork ever finish?

Comment: Instead of incrementing and checking the value of that Field in that weird manner, close the Port when the BGW completes its work, i.e, when the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised.

Comment: @Jimi issue is not of closing the port, it is of opening and reading from that port.

Comment: @Caius Jard No, the debugger hangs on the serialP.Write(send_Packet, i, 1); line, that is the issue.

Comment: @Jimi I tried closing the port in the manner you described but problem remains the same!

Comment: Hmm, I suspect "blocking" might be a more accurate term than "hanging"

Comment: The code you have now has *wild* concurrency issues. Remove the Timer and just use the BGW, the objects and methods you're using are not thread-safe (the BGW doesn't exactly create a Thread, but it's an IAsynchOperation anyway).

Comment: @Jimi I removed the timer but the issue remains the same i.e. serialRtx.IsBusy stays true for all times hence serialP.Write(send_Packet, i, 1) line gets blocked!

Comment: I don't know what code you've written and I don't know why you're checking `.IsBusy`, you don't need it. I don't even see where / when you're opening the Port. -- I've already mentioned that those objects are not thread-safe. Create the Post in the BGW's `DoWork` event, open the Port, write to it and close it in the end. When the BGW raises the `RunWorkerCompleted`, you know it has terminated. -- Let any exception pass through, so `e.Error` will be set. If you actually need to show a MessageBox, do it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.

Comment: @Jimi okay I have made changes to my code according to your suggestions and it is working well. There is just one confusion, does the Serial.RunWorkerCompleted get invoked when Serial.DoWork ends or Serial.DataReceived ends? Because I want to raise the RunWorkerCompleted event when I receive all the bytes.

Comment: The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised when the code in `DoWork` completes its work, when there's an exception (don't catch exceptions in `DoWork`, unless it's expected to receive one in specific contexts, e.g., when you enumerate and try to access files on disc, because you want to continue the enumeration, hence when the exception is not *fatal*) or `CancelAsync` is called. -- If you have a loop, when the code is done processing the data, you set `e.Result` to the computed value and exit the loop. At that point, there's no more code to run, the method completes.

Comment: The `AsyncOperation` manager (what handles the BGW Operation) automatically raises   the `RunWorkerCompleted` event when `DoWork` exits, for whatever reason. -- Remember to always check `e.Error` and `e.Canceled` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler before you read the `e.Result` value.

Comment: @Jimi I have encountered another problem now. Upon increasing the sample number (to 4000 samples) of data acquired through serial port, I am unable to receive all of the data samples using the Serial.DataReceived event and checking the Serial.BytesToRead property !Receiving less than half of the samples only. How to ensure RunWorkerCompleted 
 event gets raised only after receiving the 4000th sample of channel 8? I have updated my code too.